# Alternatives to CKAN

Tags: java, lamp, sample-data, ckan

Are you aware of alternatives to [CKAN](http://ckan.org/)? I am searching for a metadata managing portal software with a similar feature set like CKAN.

The implementation would preferably be either LAMP or Java.

Comment: Have a look at DATALHUB -> Same functionality, but a JAVA solutuion https://github.com/ais-albania/datalhub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [dataverse](http://thedata.org/).

Comment: This looks interesting, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

There's a pure Drupal based version in the works at http://drupal.org/project/dkan

Answer (score 0):

One of the few alternatives is [Socrata Open Data Portal](http://www.socrata.com/open-data-portal/). However it is neither open source nor free.

Socrata provides CKAN integration by harvesting CKAN data as stated on their website: [Socrata Delivers Straightforward Integration with CKAN](http://www.socrata.com/open-data-mandate).